# Build Query based on Conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating an API in which I am passing a value as a query to search and retrieve data from database in mongodb.

What I want to do is if I don't pass value as a query then all the documents should be retrieved.

I am missing something very little while doing this. Please do tell if any one knew how to do this.

```
gldb.find("test",
{ uid: user.idx, did: query.did)},
{},0,
function(e, d){
  if(e){
    logger.error(e);
    cb(retCode.processingError, "Error while finding emergency contacts.");
  }
  else
    cb(retCode.ok, d);
  }
);
```

}

This is sort of a function which i am using to extract the data from collection.

Now I want that if and only if the query i.e query.did is passed then only search by that query otherwise only search by uid.

Thanks and appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you looking for `find({})`?

Comment: find({}) is to be used if i don't pass any query params otherwise i use find({query})

Comment: Hmm...guess I don't understand what your question is. Can you clarify by adding some code to your question?

Comment: I have to create an API in which i will extract documents on the basis of query if and only if the query is present otherwise i will extract all documents. Should I write the code?

Comment: It is a duplicate but can you please elaborate it a little more.. I think I didn't get it.

Comment: Thank you guys :)